# How to write the given sql query in haskell using database.beam library which filters on column of type jsonb and uses subqueries

Tags: haskell, psql

##### Given a table called `mytable`

###### Table structure

| Column | Type | Nullable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | uuid | not null |
| details | jsonb |  |

###### Sample payload in `details` column of one of the row

```
{
    x: [{
            x1: 'a',
            x2: 'b'
        },
        {
            x1: 'c',
            x2: 'd'
        }
    ],
    y: {
        y1: ['d', 'e', 'f'],
        y2: ['l', 'm', 'n']
    }
}
```

###### Objective

###### Filter the rows in table with below filters:

- At least one record in `details.x` has `x1='value1'`
- `details.y.y1` is not null

###### SQL Query for the above problem statement

```
  SELECT *
  FROM mytable AS currentRow
  WHERE 'value1' = ANY (
            SELECT (jsonb_array_elements(details::jsonb->'x')->'x1')::text
            FROM mytable
            WHERE mytable.id = currentRow.id
        )
    AND EXISTS (
            SELECT jsonb_array_elements((details::jsonb->'y')::jsonb->'y1')
            FROM mytable
            WHERE mytable.id = currentRow.id
        );
```

###### Tried writing the subquery

```hs
import Database.Beam
import Database.Beam.Postgres

loadAllOffersByMerchantId :: HasCallStack => Flow [MyTable]
loadAllOffersByMerchantId = do
  runDB $ -- A local function 
    do
      findRows -- Uses runReturningList
          $ select
          $ do
              myTable <- all_ (schema.myTable)
              let subquery1 =
                      subselect_ $ pgJsonArrayElements (myTable.details ->$ x_)
                  subquery2 =
                      subselect_ $ pgJsonArrayElements (myTable.details ->$ y_) ->$ y1_
              guard_ ((val_ "value1") `in_` subquery1)
              guard_ (exists_ subquery2)
              return (od, rdsl)
  where
    x_ :: QGenExpr ctxt Postgres s Text
    x_ = "x"

    y_ :: QGenExpr ctxt Postgres s Text
    y_ = "y"

    y1_ :: QGenExpr ctxt Postgres s Text
    y1_ = "y1"
```

###### Compile-time errors

```
1.  In line: subselect_ $ pgJsonArrayElements (myTable.details ->$ x_)
    1.1 Error: Couldn't match expected type ‘Q be db (Database.Beam.Query.Internal.QNested s) r’
            with actual type ‘QGenExpr QValueContext Postgres
                                ( Database.Beam.Query.Internal.QNested QBaseScope)
                                ( beam-postgres-0.5.0.0:Database.Beam.Postgres.PgSpecific.PgSetOf
                                  ( beam-postgres-0.5.0.0:Database.Beam.Postgres.PgSpecific.PgJSONElement
                                    (json0 aeson-1.5.6.0:Data.Aeson.Types.Internal.Value)
                                  )
                                )’

    1.2 Error: Couldn't match type ‘aeson-1.5.6.0:Data.Aeson.Types.Internal.Value’
                          with ‘json0 a1’
            arising from a use of ‘GHC.Records.Extra.getField’
2.  In line: guard_ ((val_ "value1") `in_` subquery1)
    2.1 Error: Couldn't match expected type ‘[a0]’
                           with actual type ‘Q be0 db0 s0
                                              ( Database.Beam.Query.Internal.WithRewrittenThread
                                                (Database.Beam.Query.Internal.QNested s0)
                                                s0 r0
                                              )’
3. In line:  subselect_ $ pgJsonArrayElements (myTable.details ->$ y_) ->$ y1_
    3.1 Error: Couldn't match kind ‘(* -> *) -> *’
                              with ‘*’
    3.2 Error: Couldn't match expected type ‘Q be db (Database.Beam.Query.Internal.QNested s) r’
                           with actual type ‘QGenExpr QValueContext Postgres
                                              (Database.Beam.Query.Internal.QNested QBaseScope)
                                              (json0 b0)’
    3.3 Error: Couldn't match type ‘aeson-1.5.6.0:Data.Aeson.Types.Internal.Value’
                              with ‘json1 a1’
                arising from a use of ‘GHC.Records.Extra.getField’
```

Comment: What went wrong with your attempt? Compile-time error? Runtime error? Wrong output? I'm not enough familiar with SQL in Haskell to help, but I think you could provide a bit more information.

Comment: Can you please make the example complete and self-contained? For example, the definition of `MyTable` seems to be missing. I need enough info so I can reproduce the error myself in order to be able to help you.

Comment: Looking a bit closer at the error message, the error seems to be related to the definition of either `myTable` or `details`, so at the very least the definitions of those are definitely needed in order to figure out what the issue is. But preferably a full self-contained example